# Does a universal affirmation entail an existential affirmation?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have a *universal affirmative* statement (a statement of the form: ∀x(Px → Qx)), such as "all dogs go to heaven". Does an *existential affirmative* statement (a statement of the form: ∃x(Px ∧ Qx)) such as "there exists a dog, such that she went to heaven" follow from that?

Comment: No. Since ∀x(Dx → Hx) is simply ∀x(¬Dx v Hx), any model with no dogs in it (¬Dx) will make the universal _vacuously_ true. But &exist;x(Dx &and; Hx) is true only in models where there exists at least one dog who went to heaven. That suggests a counterexample: pick an arbitrary empty model and it will satisfy the universal vacuously and will fail to satisfy the existential.

Comment: Vaguely related: [What do “universal” and “existential” mean in logic?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/what-do-universal-and-existential-mean-in-logic/)

Answer (score 3):

I think that we need a more precise discussion of the above topic.

First : are we assuming *classical* logic ? From your question, it is not so clear.

But, see comment above, if we "equate" ∀x(Px → Qx) with ∀x(¬Px v Qx), then we are assuming so, because (P → Q) is equivalent to (¬P v Q) in classical logic.

Second, it seems to me that you are mixing" two different questions :

*(i)* Does a universal affirmation entail an existential affirmation?

with :

*(ii)* does an universal affirmative statement, like : ∀x(Px → Qx) entails an existential affirmative statement, like : ∃x(Px ∧ Qx) ?

For *(i)*, in *classical* logic the general answer is : **YES**. We have : ∀xDx |= ∃xDx, because the *model-theoretic* semantics for first-order logic assume that every interpretation has a not-empty domain.

Thus, if in the interpretation **I** with domain **D** we have that **all** things are Dogs, being the domain **D** not-empty, for sure there is at least one Dog.

The case of *(ii)* is different. Again, if we assume *classical* logic, we are licensed to "traslate" ∀x(Px → Qx) with ∀x(¬Px v Qx).

Now, the question is :

> does ∀x(¬Px v Qx) |= ∃x(Px ∧ Qx) ?

Of course : **NO**. As per Hunan's comment above :

> any interpretation with no dogs in it will make the universal vacuously true, because (¬Dx) is true. But if there are **no** dogs, then (Dx ∧ Hx) is always false.

But obviously [see *(i)*] we have : ∀x(Px → Qx) |= ∃x(Px → Qx).

Answer (score 1):

Domain: set of dogs

H__: __ goes to heaven

'For all d, Hd' is true for every d that exists. It doesn't state that any d does exist. So no, the universal quantifier doesn't imply the existential quantifier.

However, for arbitrary domains X,Y and arbitrary predicate Fxy, 'there exists y such that for all x, Fxy' implies that 'for all x, there exists y such that Fxy' since the existing y is the same for every x, but 'for all x, there exists y such that Fxy' does not imply 'there exists y such that for all x, Fxy' since it is possible that the existing y is different for every x.

Comment: Glad to see you participating!

Comment: You have to specify that you are working with so-called [Free Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/), otherwise the "standard" semantics for first-order logic assumes that every domain of interpreattion must be not empty. Thus, the domain = set of dogs include at least one dog and if the sentence 'For all d, Hd' is true then, being that **all** dogs go to heaven, for sure at least one dog goes; i.e. 'For all d, Hd' entails 'Exists d, Hd'.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, your first statement means: for all x, when x is P, then it is also Q (e.g. for all things x, when x is a unicorn, its skin has white color). From this it does not follow that there exists a unicorn.